# Oracle - find specific string in comments of tables

Tags: sql, oracle

There are 2000 tables in the Oracle database, and I want to get tables which comments of column contains **churn**, how can I do that?

Pseudo code

```
for table in database:
    for current_column, current_column_comment in table:
        if 'churn' in current_column_comment:
            print(table, current_column, current_column_comment)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select in all tables

```
 SELECT * FROM user_col_comments WHERE comments LIKE '%churn%';
```